# how do i select previous date using ssis expression?

Tags: sql, ssis

hi i have ssis package and following expression
which gives me todays date and time for file name

```
@[User::FilePath]+ "Bloomberg_"+REPLACE((DT_STR, 20, 1252)
(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)@[System::StartTime], ":", "")+".xls"

\\public\\Bloomberg_Upload\\Bloomberg_2013-07-05 005738.xls
```

I need to get one date previous like following only for weekdays:

```
\\public\\Bloomberg_Upload\\Bloomberg_2013-07-04 005738.xls
```

How can I do this ?

For Monday -

> If I execute my package on Monday date should be of Friday.

please guide me

i'm trying like this -

```
(DT_I4)DATEPART("weekday",@[System::StartTime]) ==2 ? 
Replace((DT_STR, 20, 1252)(DATEADD( "D", -3,@[System::StartTime])),":","-") + ".xls" :
Replace((DT_STR, 20, 1252)(DATEADD( "D", -1,@[System::StartTime])),":","-") + ".xls"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you are just trying to work out how to obtain the previous day's date and if the previous day's date happens to be the weekend then get the last workday.

You almost had it right with your code, you just needed to change your weekday constant.

This code will check to see if it is Monday and if it is then subtract 3 days otherwise subtract 1.

```
@[User::FilePath]+"Bloomberg_"+((DT_I4)DATEPART("weekday",@[System::StartTime]) ==1 ? 
Replace((DT_STR, 20, 1252)(DATEADD( "D", -3,@[System::StartTime])),":","") + ".xls" :
Replace((DT_STR, 20, 1252)(DATEADD( "D", -1,@[System::StartTime])),":","") + ".xls")
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is better to use `GETDATE()`
and then you can do the minus like this:

```
DATEADD("day", -1, GETDATE())
```

Also have a look here:
[DATEADD (SSIS Expression)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141719.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Last year:

(DT_WSTR,4)YEAR(DATEADD("yy",-1,GETDATE()))

Last Quarter:

(DT_WSTR,1)DATEPART("qq",DATEADD("qq",-1,GETDATE()))